# In codeIgniter how to extract serialize array from ajax post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**In CodeIgniter how to json decode serialize array from ajax post?**

I want to store these details based on property_id and item_definition_id.
 Here `property_id` is same for these two services. `item_definition_id` and `service_name` are different.

In this project, I have 4 type services. maintenance,`add_on`, landing and cleaning. Below this service types, there are 5-10 service names.

I want to save these details when the `user(property_id)` select services and click on the save button( save button is outside the form)

From a console, I got the serialized array like this.

```
0:{name: "service_type", value: "main"}
1:{name: "service_name", value: "Maintenance"}
2:{name: "unit", value: "Per Visit"}
3:{name: "item_definition_id", value: "26"}
4:{name: "visits", value: "14"}
5:{name: "extra_charge", value: ""}
6:{name: "override_charge", value: "3600"}
7:{name: "maintenance.level1.type1", value: ""}
8:{name: "maintenance.level1.type2", value: "1"}
9:{name: "maintenance.level1.type3", value: "1"}
10:{name: "maintenance.level1.type4", value: ""}
11:{name: "maintenance.level1.type5", value: "6"}
12:{name: "maintenance.level2.type1", value: "4"}
13:{name: "maintenance.level2.type2", value: ""}
14:{name: "maintenance.level2.type3", value: ""}
15:{name: "maintenance.level2.type4", value: "4"}
16:{name: "maintenance.level2.type5", value: "1"}
17:{name: "maintenance.level3.type1", value: ""}
19:{name: "maintenance.level3.type2", value: ""}
20:{name: "maintenance.level3.type3", value: "1"}
21:{name: "maintenance.level3.type4", value: "1"}
22:{name: "maintenance.level3.type5", value: "4"}
23:{name: "maintenance.level4.type1", value: ""}
24:{name: "maintenance.level4.type2", value: ""}
25:{name: "maintenance.level4.type3", value: ""}
26:{name: "maintenance.level4.type4", value: ""}
27:{name: "maintenance.level4.type5", value: ""}
28:{name: "maintenance.level5.type1", value: ""}
29:{name: "maintenance.level5.type2", value: ""}
30:{name: "maintenance.level5.type3", value: ""}
31:{name: "maintenance.level5.type4", value: ""}
32:{name: "maintenance.level5.type5", value: ""}
33:{name: "contract_notes", value: "4 Hour monthly visit"}
34:{name: "internal_notes", value: ""}
35:{name: "service_type", value: "add_on"}

36:{name: "service_type", value: "add_on"}
37:{name: "service_name", value: "Gutter Cleaning"}
38:{name: "unit", value: "Per Visit"}
39:{name: "item_definition_id", value: "19"}
40:{name: "visits", value: "1"}
41:{name: "gutter_cleaning_linear_feet", value: ""}
42:{name: "gutter_cleaning_greater_than_15_feet", value: ""}
43:{name: "gutter_cleaning_cannot_walk_roof", value: ""}
44:{name: "extra_charge", value: ""}
45:{name: "override_charge", value: "348"}
46:{name: "contract_notes", value: ""}
47:{name: "internal_notes", value: ""}
48:{name: "property_id", value: "173"}
49:{name: "contractDate", value: "05/02/2019"}
50:{name: "contract_id", value: "1473"}
51:{name: "duration_months", value: "12"}
```

in controller function

```
public function save_contracts(){    

    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    $newArr = [];
    foreach ($data as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            if($k == 'name') $name = $v;
            if($k == 'value') $value = $v;
        }
        $newArr[ $name ] = $value;
    }
    $UpdateItems =  $this->current_model->UpdateContracts($newArr);
    //echo $UpdateItems;

}
```

Here I got the last service_name.

Comment: Why are you sending them as serialized json when using Ajax? Can you show us your Ajax request? Also, can you explain what your actual issue is? The question only contains "I want..." and no explanation about what actually happens when you run your code.

Comment: Yes. var data = JSON.stringify( serviceData ).toString();
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'admin/new_contracts/save_contracts',
  data: {data : data },
  beforeSend:function(data){  
   $body.addClass("loading");
        },
  success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
   $body.removeClass("loading");
  },
  error:function(data){
     alert('Something happend, Please try again !');
  },
 });

Comment: Please edit your question to include the above code. It's pretty unreadable in a comment. Also, if you're using jQuery's Ajax function, there's no reason to serialize and then decode your data. jQuery will handle that for you.

Comment: In my form, the input box name will change based on the service type and service name. Eg: 'window_cleaning' , the meta_keys will be window_front,window_back and window_right. But in 'Carpet_cleaning' there is only one input box and the meta_key is square_footage.

Comment: I'm not sure how that comment applies to anything I said, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `$postData = $this->input->post();` for post

and  `$getData = $this->input->get();`

and access each fild `$post['service_type]`

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html?highlight=post#CI_Input::get_post

Comment: I cant use this method. because  some field names change as per the service_name.